# Elevation obtained from USGS DEM is different from Lidar elevation

Tags: dem, lidar, usgs

For a project I'm working on I need to calculate height of objects for which I know their spatial 2D coordinates (e.g. buildings). I'm using Lidar data to extract the highest Z value for an object, and then I subtract from it the ground elevation obtained from a DEM.

However, after getting some inconsistencies in heights calculated that way, I thought I should compare the ground level of the DEM I'm using with that of the Lidar data.

In all the tests I've done I found that the elevation I got from the DEM is larger than the ground level obtained from the Lidar data by about 2 meters.

I obtained both the DEM and the Lidar data from USGS. As the Lidar data points to use in the comparison I used points classified as ground (Classification = 2).

The area I used for the comparison is in Chicago, Illinois. The DEM I was using is for Cook county, it is in latitude/longitude coordinates. It is a raster tif file. The Lidar data is in EPSG:3435 CRS. Both are using, as far as I understand, GRS-80 ellipsoid.

I compared a sample of 1000 random points selected from the Lidar data, and I also compared points of a flat, open field that is about 200 x 200 square meters. I verified that the points I compared are of the same area. For the open field, the DEM data says its average height is 183.5 meters, the Lidar data says it is 181 meters. In both tests the height distribution was very narrow, with a standard deviation about 0.35.

The tests, and my project, are written in R.

I was expecting to get, more or less, the same value for ground elevation, and I don't understand why the values are so different. Am I missing something, or is something wrong with the method I'm using for the comparison?

Edit

I'm adding links to the specific Lidar and DEM data I was looking at:

- [Lidar](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5d69480ee4b0c4f70cf22cf4)
- [DEM](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/5deb32bbe4b02caea0f0eb6f)

Comment: The USGS has DEMs of different quality and sources so you should tell us which ones you are using.  If you go to the National Map and search your area for 1m DEMs, those will likely be from LiDAR.  Those the ones you should be comparing with your LiDAR ground.  These are probably hydroflattened and they may have break lines introduced as well, so those will introduce some differences.

Comment: Thanks. I've edited my question and added links to the specific DEM and Lidar sources. I'm not sure whether it is a 1m DEM - it is 1/3 arc. I'm quiet new to this subject, I'll look further into it.

Comment: Your USGS datasource is, as you state, 1/3 arc second resolution. This translates to (roughly) 10 metres (sorry, European here). More importantly, the USGS DEM was obtained by satellite, whereas a LiDAR datasets are usually obtained from aircrafts or drones. Differences between the two datasets of roughly 2.5 m are nothing unusual.

Comment: Thanks. I guess the issue is not with the DEM resolution, as the area I've been looking at has a very small slope. So it probably the other issue. So if I need to be able to calculate heights (as difference between two points), I figure I need to either find a DEM that was generated from Lidar and has higher resolution, or use the Lidar itself as a source for ground elevation. (and meters are fine :))